# How to read multiple .tar files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm trying to read a .tar file, it works fine but sometimes the filename is a bit different. 
The filename sometimes changes from `filename_01.tar` to `filename_02.tar`
I have tried using `filename_*.tar` but that doesn't seem to work.

I know it's a basic question but I can't figure it out.

My code: (using python 3.7+)

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open('filename_01.tar')
tar.extractall('locationfolder')
tar.close
```

Comment: loop on the files using `glob.glob`. Nothing to do with `tar`

Comment: did you try [os.walk()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) and then untar everyfile on its or if you are using Ubuntu try `tar -zxvf *.tar.gz`

Comment: Thanks works fine. I forgot tot use the glob.glob

Answer (score 2):

`*` isn't expanded by `tar` command. You can create a loop with `glob.glob` on the required pattern. Also, better use `with` syntax to open the file, so there's no typo when calling `tar.close` without parentheses, which does nothing.

```
import tarfile,glob

for f in glob.glob('filename_*.tar'):
   with tarfile.open(f) as tar:
       tar.extractall('locationfolder')
```